# how to execute a query where username and hashed password match from couchbase server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, couchbase

select query for login page when the user enter details of username and password, based on details the query executes and user logins. here the password is encrypted using bycryptjs, can anyone help me how to write query for hashed password

```
    Model.postUser = function(data, callback) 
            {
                  var statement = "SELECT uName,fName,lName " +
                                " FROM `" + config.couchbase.bucket + "` AS users " +
                                "WHERE uName = '"+ data.uName +"'pwd = '"+ bcrypt.hashSync(data.pwd, 10) +"' ";
            var query = N1qlQuery.fromString(statement);
            db.query(query, function(error, result) 
                        {

                            if(error) 
                            {
                                return callback(error, null);
                            }
                            callback(null, result);
                        }
                   );    
        };

 //This is an insert function for saving data in database.

    Model.save = function(data, callback)
        {
        var jsonObject = {
                            uName       : data.uName,
                            pwd         : bcrypt.hashSync(data.pwd, 10),
                            pin         : data.pin,
                            cpin        : data.cpin,
                            fName       : data.fName,
                            lName       : data.lName

                        }

                    var documentId = data.document_id ? data.document_id : uuid.v4();
                    db.insert(documentId, jsonObject, function(error, result) {
                       //password validation using bcrypt
                       db.get(documentId,jsonObject,function(error, result) {


                        if(error) {
                            callback(error, null);
                            return;
                        }
                        callback(null, {message: "success", data: result});
                    });
        }
```

Comment: You don't "decrypt" password hashes, you hash what you want to check it with and compare them, or with bcrypt you'd use the `compare` method.

Comment: in above code both are two different functions how can i compare the hash  console.log("Password Match ->"+ bcrypt.compareSync(data.pwd, result[0].pwd));